# Дубликаты в JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Как в spring data jpa бороться с дубликатами? Например мне нужно сохранить профиль с листом тегов и со связью многие ко многим. При сохранении отдельно одинаковых тегов ,которые уже есть или профиля с каскадом - теги дублируются в таблице. Column(unique = true) или NaturalID при дублировании тега по аннотированному полю выкидывает эксепшн о дубликате, но мне нужно игнорить дубликат или перезаписывать. 
Реализовал [следующий пример](https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/05/10/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) через спринговский JpaRepository, но опять же эксепшн при сохранении post2, тогда как с post1 всё отлично.
Вроде как тривиальная задача, как решить

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне известно, решить эту проблему на уровне JPA нельзя. Но можно нагородить свой велосипед:

```
@Service
public class TagService {
    private final Map<String, Tag> tags = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Lock lock = new Lock();

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        tagRepository.findAll()
          .forEach(i -> tags.put(i.getName(), i));
    }

    public Tag newTag(String name) {
        return tags.computeIfAbsent(name, name -> new Tag(name));
    }

    public Tag getTag(String name) {
        return tags.computeIfAbsent(name, name -> tagRepository.findByName(name));
    }

    public boolean save() {
        boolean locked = false;
        try {
            locked = lock.tryLock();
            if (locked) {
                tagRepository.saveAll(tags.values()
                                       .stream()
                                       .filter(i -> i.getId() == null)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                  .forEach(i -> tags.put(i.getName(), i));
                return true;
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (locked)
                lock.unlock();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Остаётся только получать экземпляры `Tag` из сервиса и вызывать `tagService.save()` до сохранения сущностей типа `Post`.

**P.S.** Буду очень рад, если кто-нибудь сможет подсказать более изящное решение, но не дёргающее БД чаще.

Comment: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.testnaturalid.model.Tag;

Вылетает такой эксепшн. Хотя если нету дубликатов - сохраняется всё хорошо.
Прилагаю код :https://gist.github.com/konstantinx/0fcedbb9dc0f05cc051b20eb330c82d3

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. Тег - сущность независимая (она существует независимо от профилей), то и создается она самостоятельно, независимо от профилей, так ведь? Если так, то перед сохранением профиля, сначала, нужно сохранить список тегов.

Чтобы, при этом, избежать ошибки с дубликатами, список тегов сохраняется не сразу списком (например, `repo.save(tagList)`), а в цикле, сохраняя результаты в отдельную коллекцию:

```
for (Tag tag : tagList) {
    try {
        resultList.add(repo.save(tag));   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // обработка ошибки
    }
}
```

Затем возвращаем клиенту коллекцию с результатами (или комбинированный ответ с двумя списками - удачно сохраненными тегами и дубликатами).

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Я сам изначально делал подобно, вручную.Но это рождает много лишнего кода и запросов для простого по сути действия сохранения тегов. Поэтому нужен выход из ситуации через саму базу или jpa

Comment: @КанстанцінЛукашэвіч Если найдешь, не забудь отписать здесь, плиз...

Answer (score 0):

Column(unique = true) и try {} catch(){}

**Update**

```
try{
//your add to db code
}catch(Exception e) {
//do nothing
}
```

**Update 2**
Вот так

```
public void addTag(Tag tag) {
    try{
    tags.add(tag);
    tag.getPosts().add(this);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: Таким образом вы будете игнорировать exception с дубликацией

Comment: Только при этом не сохранится ни одна сущность в текущей транзакции, ни тэги по которым нет дубликатов, ни посты.